# Refrigeration of Cream Liquor

Tags: food-safety, refrigerator, alcohol

I recently bought a bottle of Jackson Morgan cream liquor.  The alcohol content on the bottle is listed at 15%.  After looking up when alcohol percentage becomes a preservative I found an article that stated:

> If it’s under 15% alcohol or if the base is wine, it goes in the fridge once it’s open.

Even though it says *under* 15% and this is listed at *exactly* 15%, it seems a little too close for comfort for me where I want some more information.  I was wondering if anyone had any experience or references on the following:

- Is it safe to keep the cream liquor on the bar top?
- When does the percentage of alcohol become a valid preservative?

Link to the article referencing the above quote: https://food52.com/blog/16656-which-alcohols-should-be-refrigerated-why

Comment: does the bottle say "refrigerate after opening" ?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that part. It does not say refrigerate after opening.

Comment: I'd guess, generally, that a safety recommendation would want to have a margin already built in for edge cases, so as to avoid potential problems.  They don't want the trouble of guessing wrong or cutting the margin too fine.  I wouldn't be surprised if the hard number for preservation is a little less than 15%, just rounded up for ease and/or extra caution.  I am however not sure, so use your own judgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between 6-18 months is the usual number. Refrigeration isn't required, but certainly will help. Bailey's claims to be fine for two years, but no other site backs up their claim.

I can't find anything specific on "Jackson Morgan Cream Liqueur"; they don't seem to have any sort of expiration information on their site. I'd err on the side of caution and try to knock it out inside a year, and refrigerate when possible.

As with many other dairy based products, it's incredibly obvious when it begins to spoil. Taste, color, and texture will all go notably off before it becomes harmful to drink.

[Citation](https://www.thespruceeats.com/shelf-life-of-distilled-spirits-760730)

[Other Citation](https://stilltasty.com/Fooditems/index/17017)